# Git merge commits from split repository

Tags: git

I'm in the process of splitting up a repository, but other developers are still working on the old repository. How would I go about merging the changes that have been made to the old repository to the new ones after the split?

As an example, `project_repo` has the structure

```
project_repo
 |
 |---gui
 |---server
```

and the two subdirectories are split into their on repositories, `gui` and `server`. The last commit was `abc123`

A developer has been working on changes to the gui on the old repository, and pushes his changes as commit `xyz987`, making the history in `project_repo`:

```
commit xyz987
Author: Joe Developer
...

commit abc123
Author: John Doberman
...

commit cde456
Author Jenny Donald
...
```

Since the changes are only in the old repository, the new `gui` repository is still at commit `abc123`, it's history being

```
commit abc123
Author: John Doberman
...

commit cde456
Author Jenny Donald
...
```

How to I apply commit `xyz987` from `project_repo` on the new `gui` repository?

Comment: While abc123 may be an example sha1, I presume that the split repo actually has a different sha1 tip - because they have differing (split) history. You should develop a script that compares the two repos and see if the new commits to the old repo affect files within each of the new repos, and then simply commit those changes (perhaps add the old sha1). At some point declare a change over day and retire the old repo and stop using the script.

Comment: cherry-pick from the old repository (add it as a remote or just fetch from it)